# Returning a value from asynchronous PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous

I would like to return a value from an asynchronous function in PHP ... I use icicle.io here, but I'm happy to use whatever, provided it does what I want to do!  Anyway, this is some code below

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Icicle\Coroutine\Coroutine;
use Icicle\Loop;

function getArray($int) {
    yield array ($int, $int + 1, $int + 2);
}

function getArrays() {
    $numbers = array (1, 4, 7);
    $results = array();

    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        array_push($results, (yield(getArray($number))));
    }

    yield call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results);
}

$coroutine = new Coroutine(getArrays());

$data = $coroutine->then(
    function ($result) {
        $data = print_r($result, true);
        return "Result: {$data}\n";
    },
    function (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    }
)->done(function ($value) {
    echo $value;
});

Loop\run();
```

What I'd *really* like to do is to put that last little bit in a function, so it looks more like this:

```
function sync() {
    $coroutine = new Coroutine(getArrays());

    $data = $coroutine->then(
        function ($result) {
            $data = print_r($result, true);
            return "Result: {$data}\n";
        },
        function (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        }
    )->done(function ($value) {
        return $value;
    });

    Loop\run();

    return /* the value */;
}
```

Then from my cool software, I can call sync() as if it's a **synchronous** function, blissfully unaware of the asynchronous shenanigans going on behind the scenes.

Has anyone done this, or have some suggestions as to how I might?  At the moment the *best* I've come up with is (ab)using the output buffer & `serialize()`/`unserialize()` functions, but since I'm doing it all out of some desire to improve the performance, that seems rather backwards!!

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronously wait for the resolution of an Awaitable (including a Coroutine) by using the `wait()` method. This method ticks the event loop until the coroutine is resolved. This means your `sync()` function can simply call this method on the coroutine object and return the result.

```
function sync() {
    $coroutine = new Coroutine(getArrays());
    return $coroutine->wait();
}
```